# How does the scan operator help to identify indices where a rule holds for 2 observations in a row?

Tags: kdb

A boolean vector has been created based on some rule and we need to identify the indices where the rule holds for 2 observations in a row. The following code does that

```
indices:0101001101b
runs:{0 x\x}"f"$;
where 2=runs indices
```

Could you please help me understand how the scan operator is used in the definition of the runs function? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's using this special shorthand commonly used in calculating exponential moving averages: https://code.kx.com/q/ref/accumulators/#alternative-syntax

So `{0 x\x}` is equivalent to:

```
q){z+x*y}\[0;indices;indices]
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1
```

What this is doing is essentially using the booleans as an on/off switch (via the boolean multiplication) for the rolling sum. It adds (`z+`) until it hits a negative boolean in which case the rolling sum resets back to zero.

In english: `nextValue` + [`currentValue (starting at 0)` * `nextValue`]

When `nextValue` is `1`, 1 gets added. When `nextValue` is `0` the result is zero (resetting the rolling sum).

Something like this can achieve the same thing, though no less easy to read at a glance (and using two scans instead of one):

```
q){s-maxs not[x]*s:sums x}indices
0 1 0 1 0 0 1 2 0 1i
```

Answer (score 1):

Terry has answered your question about *how* `runs` works.

Comparing adjacent items is common. You might prefer to use the `prior` keyword. Certainly easier to see what it is doing.

```
q)where (and) prior indices
,7
```